# How do you get SQL Azure to work with TrustServerCertificate=false?

Tags: security, azure-sql-database

Subtitle - How do I actually connect to SQL Azure securely without Man in the middle attacks?

I can use a ADO.net connection string with TrustServerCertificate=true and connect to the server successfully. But by doing that I would lose protection against a man-in-the-middle attack where the communication with the server is hijacked, and an unknown certificate is used to establish the connection. So I want to use TrustServerCertificate=false.

The only problem is, now I get the error that the connection fails trust validation. I expect the solution to this is that I need to install the SQL Azure's server certificate in one of my certificate stores. The problem is I have no idea how to get the server certificate. Help?

Comment: So suddenly, it seems like everything is working. With TrustServerCertificate=false. I don't quite believe my eyes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To validate the certificate in the ADO.Net world you need to have `Encrypt=True` and `TrustServerCertificate=False` for it to work. Did you have `Encrypt=True` in your orginal scenario?

A good read on SQL Azure security can be found on the wiki below:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connection-security.aspx

Comment: You are correct, plus there was an issue of user education. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

[edited] To answer myself in long-winded way:

I think I was misunderstanding the cause of the problem. The `TrustServerCertificate=false` parameter, was not the problem.

There was some other transient issue, possibly certificate revocation checks, or a bad certificate, or network issue, which were causing the problem. This had to be resolved in order to connect -- but this is by design, for having a properly secure connection.

Getting the server ceritificate and installing the certificate in question in the certificate store as a Trusted certificate, would possibly have allowed connecting to the server with this certificate, but I am not sure it is a good idea - does that bypass the revocation check?

Comment: After reading them a couple times, I can't tell the difference between your descriptions of "What I guessed it means" and "What it actually means".